# Cordova-SQLitePlugin per-populated sqlite database

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am using [Cordova-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) in Cordova for android application. I have created sqlite database using SQLite Administrator with table Tests and one record in this table. I added test.db in the www folder near index.html. But on emulator reciving error : 'no such table'  when this code is executed:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'test'});
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("Select count(*) From Tests;", [], function(tx, res) {
      alert(res); 
    });

    }, function(e) {
      alert("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
}

$(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```

It seem that db is recreated. How can fix this?